# How to Simulate CPU workload in nodejs app?

Tags: node.js

I'm working on building a simple app that I can use to test out microservice scaling.  I have a simple node.js webserver running with a few routes, but now I need to find something to run that will use some CPU when hitting the routes.

Right now I have a listener up that starts a child process and calculates prime numbers.  In my testing it may take a decent while to generate primes up to 100,000,000.... but even with 10+ child process running I am not seeing any real CPU load. So guessing this single threaded type of math equation isn't a great use case.

Can anyone point me to some simple to run things in JS that will burn some CPU?

Comment: Have you tried 100+ child processes??? What kind of load are you expecting? Maybe more important that using node.js to test, you can just generally test the CPU against what you think it will need to handle.

Comment: I just actually did 100 processes after switching to fibonacci and was able to kick up my CPU to 100%.  I was running 10 concurrently before and it wasn't breaking a sweat.

Answer (score 0):

[This page](https://yarin.dev/nodejs-cpu-bound-tasks-worker-threads/) was exactly what I was looking for and trying to do.  After changing over to worker threads instead of child processes, I was able to simulate 100 concurrent requests and finally started hammering my CPU.